# Polyval for multiple variable

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking for a function to calculate the value of a polynomial with multiple variables. For 2d polynomials, I use `numpy.polyval`, I have values of coefficients as a list and value for x.

I wonder if there is a similar function for x, y, z space so that my input was values of coefficients and value for x, y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

[link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval2d.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval2d)

> Evaluate a 2-D polynomial at points (x, y).
>
> This function returns the value
>
> p(x,y) = \sum_{i,j} c_{i,j} * x^i * y^j
>
> The parameters x and y are converted to arrays only if they are tuples
>   or a lists, otherwise they are treated as a scalars and they must have
>   the same shape after conversion. In either case, either x and y or
>   their elements must support multiplication and addition both with
>   themselves and with the elements of c.
>
> If c has fewer than two dimensions, ones are implicitly appended to
>   its shape to make it 2-D. The shape of the result will be c.shape[2:]
>   + x.shape.
>
> Parameters:
>
> x, y : array_like, compatible objects
>
> The two dimensional series is evaluated at the points (x, y), where x
>   and y must have the same shape. If x or y is a list or tuple, it is
>   first converted to an ndarray, otherwise it is left unchanged and, if
>   it isn’t an ndarray, it is treated as a scalar.
>
> c : array_like
>
> Array of coefficients ordered so that the coefficient of the term of
>   multi-degree i,j is contained in c[i,j]. If c has dimension greater
>   than two the remaining indices enumerate multiple sets of
>   coefficients.
>
> Returns:
>
> values : ndarray, compatible object The values of the two dimensional
>   polynomial at points formed with pairs of corresponding values from x
>   and y.